# Correctly evaluating string value and format it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need some assistance with correctly implementing a method that uses `.split` and `.replace` to format a string value passed to it.

The string value is 90% of the time an HTML link as per this example: `<a href=\"http://www.fnb.co.za\" rel=\"nofollow\">SMC RBJacobs</a>`. But sometimes it only contains a normal string value such as: `SMC RBJacobs`.

I thought it would be a good idea to evaluate the value by checking `.indexOf('</a>')`, **but this evaluates to true all the time**.(?) I then get an error in the next statements executed in my method.

**Here is my method:**

```
if (col.name === 'twitter_tweet.source') {
    var str = value;
    if (value != null || value != undefined) {
        if (value.indexOf('</a>')) {
            var parts = str.split('"nofollow\">');
            var value = parts[1].replace('</a>', '');
            return value;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

**The desired output regardless of whether the string contains HTML markup or not**: SMC RBJacobs *(or whichever name is passed)*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: better use regexp, its better for me in that type of issues.

Comment: [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1` if the search value has not been found, hence the `if` condition is wrong and should be `if (value.indexOf('</a>') > -1) { ... }`

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón that is a good idea. Do you perhaps have something in mind that will work in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` always returns a number, not a boolean. If found, the index will be zero or more. If not found the index will be -1. So you want to check like:

```
if (value.indexOf('</a>') > -1) {
```

If you can have different tags and spacing I would suggest using something less brittle like jQuery:

```
if ($(value).length) {
  return $(value).text();
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it slipped my mind (returning a value and not a boolean)! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try following approach:

```
var str = '<a href=\"http://www.fnb.co.za\" rel=\"nofollow\">SMC RBJacobs</a>',
el = document.createElement('div'),
result;

el.innerHTML = str;
result = el.textContent;

console.log(result);
```

**Note #1**: I assume here that HTML string is safe.
**Note #2**: `str` can be an HTML or string.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/655uqc0f/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am retrieving the value from a DB through, and not from my view. :)